# Whats wrong with this aspect

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I only want this invoked when a property is set. Why is this not working?

```
[DirtyTrackingAttribute(AttributeTargetElements =
   PostSharp.Extensibility.MulticastTargets.Property)]
class Program
{

    public static string Test { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestIt();
        Test = "foo";
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void TestIt()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Real method called");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class DirtyTrackingAttribute : OnMethodInvocationAspect
{
    public override void OnInvocation(MethodInvocationEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property invoked");
        eventArgs.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the aspect to be applied on property setters only, you can filter the method name with the expression "set_*":

```
[DirtyTrackingAttribute(AttributeTargetMembers="set_*")]
```

PostSharp 1.* does not support explicitely properties; property accessors are considered as plain methods.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could filter on property names directly on the attribute ...
I've also just played once with PostSharp, where I wanted to intercept on property access as well, and this is how i've done it:
http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html